# WinApi error code 193. Check 'evopdftohtml.dat'

Tags: c#, html, pdf, evopdf

```
string pdfFileName = txtpdfpath.Text.ToString();
PdfToHtmlConverter pdfToHtmlConverter = new PdfToHtmlConverter();
pdfToHtmlConverter.CreateIndexFile = false;
var outputDirectory = @"C:/";
pdfToHtmlConverter.PdfToolFullPath= txtpdfpath.Text.ToString();
pdfToHtmlConverter.ConvertPdfPagesToHtmlFile(pdfFileName, outputDirectory, "output");
```

this is my sample code here im trying to convert pdf to html but its throwing an exception like

> WinApi error code 193. Check 'evopdftohtml.dat' file has execute permissions and that it exists near the DLL or set the PdfToolFullPath property with the full path of the file

even after setting PdfToolFullPath property with the full path of the file im facing the same exception

can anyone helpme on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On what Windows version are you trying to use the library?

What is the exact value you set PdfToolFullPath ?

PdfToolFullPath should be the full file name of evopdftohtml.dat